# passing multiple parameters to resulthandlers in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there a way to extend the ResultEvent class in flex. i have the following code:

var token:AsyncToken = remoteObject.setQueryAndGetPromptValues('country', queryString);

```
            token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(resultCountrySearch,faultCountrySearch));
```

var token:AsyncToken = remoteObject.setQueryAndGetPromptValues('company', queryString);
                token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(resultCompanySearch,faultCompanySearch));

so once the RPC call is executed I get a ResultEvent which is handled by resultCountrySearch or resultCompanySearch, each of which updates the corresponding text field. I have 30 such prompts so I do not want to create 30 different handler functions. Is there a way that I could pass which text field to update to the resultHandler along with the result event.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to add your variables to to the asyncToken as object properties and the use them in the resulthandler

```
token.myprop = myvar;
```

Comment: ditto + upvote.  I seem to remember in flex 2 that you needed to use bracket notation on the token, so internally I require developers to use bracket notation when adding properties to tokens.  (though I could be making up the flex 2 thing...)

Comment: can you please share entire syntax of setting variables and then using them in resulthandler

Answer (score 1):

There IS a way because the [Swiz library](http://swizframework.org/) does it for you. All you have to do is call `executeServiceCall(call, resultHandler, faultHandler, eventArgs)`, and the `evertArgs` array is passed through as an argument to whichever handler is called.

I don't know all the implementation details, but it's an open source library, so you can have a poke around at their [`DynamicResponder`](http://code.google.com/p/swizframework/source/browse/trunk/src/org/swizframework/rpc/DynamicResponder.as?r=33) class (implements `IResponder`) to see the Swiz approach. It's probably best to read the [relevant documentation](http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Service+Layer) first of course (don't worry, it's short!).

Alternatively you could just use the library, though that may not be practical for your requirements.